# Flutter - How to have a non-scrollable max height ListView.builder?

Tags: flutter, dart

My problems with `ListView.builder` in my specific scenario:

- A height has to be given to `ListView.builder` so that whatever is inside that can be infinitely scrollable.
- The `shrinkWrap` property is only helpful if you are planning to give `ListView.builder` a predetermined height.

What I require:

A `ListView.builder` that acts just like a `Column` which will display all the widgets so that there is no scrolling, so it does not require a height but will be like an `Expanded` widget.

I want to use `ListView.builder` as my widgets are generated through **Lists and Dictionaries**, but if it's not necessary to use it, please give me an alternative where I can use my Lists and Dictionaries to generate widgets on demand and update the state.

Example:

```
List<Map> data = [{'data': 'here'}];

// ListView.builder solution:
ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: data.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        if (condition A) {
            return Text(data[index]['data']);
        } else if (condition B) {
            return Text(data[index]['data']);
        } else {
            return Container();
        }
    }
);
// This solution requires ListView.builder to have its own height
// constraints, so setting a height will cause it to be scrollable if
// the widgets take up space after those constraints are exceeded.
// NeverScrollablePhysics() is not the point here.

// Column solution:
// A widget and for loop is required to build before the build method is called:
List<Widget> widgetList = [];

for (var dataSet in data) {
    // If conditions here:
    widgetList.add(dataSet['data'];
}

return Column(
    children: widgetList,
);
// Problem: Widgets such as FilterChip which use state changes don't
// get updated as these come from a prebuilt Widget variable. Tapping
// on them does nothing.
```

Comment: you can use wrap widget for that

Comment: `a non-scrollable max height ListView.builder` can be just column widget?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I am confused about using a column due to using Lists and Dictionaries, the number of widgets to display is dynamic/varible, and I also need to update the state because I use widgets like checkboxes.

Comment: I think a sample snippet that will reproduce the specific issue will help to understand the error you are trying to overcome

Comment: @Jiehfeng check my code. I updated it for your case.

Comment: A `Column` works perfectly fine with dynamic lists as well

Comment: Although it's not entirely clear to me how you want it to behave if it doesn't fit in the available space. Could you maybe provide a minimum example?

Comment: @Ivo I have updated the question with example code and explanations, hope my issue is now understood.

Comment: @Ivo If I can use a `Column`, the problem is sorted for me. But the key issue is `State`, if you can help me update the state of a `Widget` variable that was assigned/initialized in the past, and allow wigets such as `FilterChip` to update when tapped on, it is sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if I understood it right, but if-conditions and loops are certainly also possible in `Columns`. Your example of

```
ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: data.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        if (condition A) {
            return Text(data[index]['data']);
        } else if (condition B) {
            return Text(data[index]['data']);
        } else {
            return Container();
        }
    }
);
```

can be rewritten as a `Column` like

```
Column(children: [
  for (final d in data)
    if (condition A)
      Text(d['data'])
    else if (condition B)
      Text(d['data'])
    else
      Container()
]);
```

But I'm not sure if it helps solve your problem.

EDIT:
For your follow-up question, maybe this is something that you want?

```
Column(children: [
  for (final d in data.map((e) => e['data']))
    if (conditionA)
      Text(d)
    else if (conditionB)
      Text(d)
    else
      Container()
]);
```

Comment: That's awesome, did not realize for loops can be written inside Columns. I will try this now and get back here with an update.

Comment: Yeah it's a pretty neat feature of Dart that I haven't seen in other programming languages. It allows conditions when creating collections. They call it a "collection for" and "collection if". Check out https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists and when you scroll down a bit it explains it

Comment: I was aware of the if conditions but not the for loops, do you know if assigning variables is possible within these for loops? For example here, can I create `final e = d['Test']` and use `e` inside the widgets that comes inside the if conditions for simplicity?

Comment: Also I can report that this solution worked perfectly and even the `State` is updating just fine. Thank you.

Comment: I'm afraid that creating variables inside there is not possible as far as I know

Comment: @Jiehfeng not sure if it helps but see my addition to the answer. Something like this is possible

Comment: That would help in certain scenarios I believe, but in others I would need multiple variables, not just one. For example a `List<Map>` where the Maps themselves contain their own `List<Map>`, I would love to set initial variables before I reach my if conditions for quick coding. Maybe I should try adding that as a suggestion to Flutter/Dart if possible.

Answer (score 1):

ListView widget contains a property named "Physics" which can accept "NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()" and that will disable scrolling in your ListView widget. here is an example,

```
return Scaffold(
  body: ListView.builder(
    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    itemCount: 10,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(),
  ),
);
```

Comment: This is not the issue at all, disabling scrolling is not what I desire, but making the ListView of maximum height.